# Round formatted time value to the nearest half-hour

Tags: php, rounding

I need 0:30 through 0:59 to round down to 0:30.
I need 0:00 through 0:29 to round up to 0:30.

Example: 08:56 will round down to 08:30 where 09:00 and 09:01 will need to round up to 09:30.
Seconds should be omitted or rounded to :00

Comment: In what cases you don't round minutes to 30? It seems that you can use `date('H:30')` everytime.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why don't you just do this:

```
$hour = date('H');
$minute = (date('i')>30)?'30':'00';
echo "$hour:$minute";
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/3wV29b5i)

**UPDATE**
I just realized that you asked all time to be rounded to `:30`:

```
$hour = date('H');
$minute = '30'; //always 30
echo "$hour:$minute";
```

Comment: date(n) is not for minute, its for month. Minute = i, hour = H, Secound = s

Answer (score 7):

My solution to a real round are the next options:

```
//Round Down
date('H:i',floor(time() / (15 * 60)) * (15 * 60))

//Round Up/Down
date('H:i',round(time() / (15 * 60)) * (15 * 60))

//Round Up
date('H:i',ceil(time() / (15 * 60)) * (15 * 60))
```

Replace `time()` with the time you need, and `15` with the minutes you like to round near to.

Example:

```
$currentTime = time();
echo('Current Time: ' . date('H:i',$currentTime) . '<br>Rounded Up 15 Minutes time: ' . date('H:i',ceil($currentTime / (15 * 60)) * (15 * 60)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
you have to do: 

$hour = date('H'); 
$minute = date('i');
$minute = ($minute < 30 || $minute > 30) ? 30 : $minute;
```

Comment: all time is less than or greater than 30, else 30 :-) might as well do `$minute = '30'`

Comment: I know, thats what he says, well better $minute = 30 :)

Comment: @VuralAcar: Maybe it's a joke, but your code only returns 30, whatever the minute is! See [Codepad](http://codepad.org/V7e4sr3H).

Comment: You answered to the original question, but you may have used `$minute = 30` only.