# Round Datetime to the next 15 minutes

Tags: php, html, time

in my project I need to round a date time e.g "08:10" to "08:00".

more examples

"8:20 to 8:15"
"8:31 to 8:30"

And in the next step i need an extra method to round up.

example
"8:20 to 8:30"
"8:31 to 8:45"

```php
$shiftInPre = new \DateTime($row["time_start"] /* <-e.g. 8:02*/);
echo roundtoLastQuarterHour($shiftInPre);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round formatted time value to the nearest half-hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127965/round-formatted-time-value-to-the-nearest-half-hour)

Comment: Function for arbitrarily rounding PHP DateTimes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57399274/339440

Answer (score 0):

If you have just `H:i` and not full datetime, use basic string operations

```
$shiftInPre = '8:07';
list($hours, $mins) = explode(':', $shiftInPre);
$mins = $hours * 60 + $mins;

$rounded = round($mins / 15) * 15;
echo floor($rounded / 60) . ':' . str_pad($rounded % 60, 2, 0); 
// 8:07 >> 8:00
// 8:08 >> 8:15
// 8:18 >> 8:15
```

Answer (score -1):

If you really need/want to use `DateTime`-Objects, you could manipulate the `DateTime`-Object with the `modify`-method based on the minutes and after that zero the seconds and microseconds with the `setTime`-method.

```php
// round (floor)
$date = new DateTime('2019-01-01T15:03:01.012345Z');
$i = $date->format('i') % 15;
$date->modify("-{$i} minute");
$date->setTime($date->format('H'), $date->format('i'), 0, 0);
var_dump($date);
```

```php
// round (ceil)
$date = new DateTime('2019-01-01T15:03:01.012345Z');
$i = 15 - ($date->format('i') % 15);
$date->modify("+{$i} minute");
$date->setTime($date->format('H'), $date->format('i'), 0, 0);
var_dump($date);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/MIGiG

This approach has the benefit for correctly handling times that will be rounded to the next day.

But if you only need to "round" a simple string containing hour and minute, then a solution involving explode and simple math is enough (See: [Answer posted panther](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56639806/1970822)).